# Pasar de la sentencia if-else a switch

Tags: c

Tengo este código que transforma las calificaciones de nuestro sistema que introduzcas al de Estados Unidos. Y me piden cambiarlo de la sentencia `if-else` a la de `switch`, y pues comienzo a pensar que no sería posible porque debe evaluar una condición con decimales. Este es el código:

```
/*El programa muestra primero una tabla de notas con sus equivalentes en el Standard Grading System o el sistema utilizado 
en los Estados Unidos que va desde la A hasta la F.  El programa preguntará al usuario su nota y transformará ese resultado 
al equivalente en el Standard Grading System.  También el programa dará una pequeña pero valiosa recomendación al usuario 
respecto a su nivel de estudio y calidad como estudiante.*/

#include "stdio.h" 
#include <windows.h> 
void clrscr()/*Creando funcion para limpiar pantalla.*/ 
{   
    HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);   
    COORD coord = {0, 0};   
    DWORD count; 

    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;   
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdOut, &csbi); 

    FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hStdOut, ' ', csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y, coord, &count); 
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOut, coord); 
} 

int main() 
{  
    int salir,saliryesno;  
    salir=0;  
    while(salir==0)
    {   clrscr();/*Llamando la funcion para limpiar pantalla.*/   
        int a;   
        float nota;   
        printf("\n\t\t\tNOTAS\t\tEQUIVALENTE\n");
        printf("\t\t     9.0 - 10.0\t\t     A\n");      
        printf("\t\t     8.5 -  8.9\t\t     B+\n");      
        printf("\t\t     8.0 -  8.4\t\t     B\n");     
        printf("\t\t     7.5 -  7.9\t\t     C+\n");     
        printf("\t\t     7.0 -  7.4\t\t     C\n");    
        printf("\t\t     6.0 -  6.9\t\t     D\n");   
        printf("\t\t     0.0 -  6.0\t\t     F\n");    
        a=0;   
        while(a==0)
        {
            printf("\nIntroduzca su nota en Programacion II: ");    
            scanf("%f",&nota);    
            if(nota<0 || nota>10)
            {     /*a sigue valiendo cero y no se sale del ciclo*/    
            }    
            else
            {     
                a=1;    
            }   
        }   
        if(nota>=9)
        {
            printf("\nNOTA EQUIVALENTE EN STANDARD GRADING SYSTEM: A\n");    
            printf("RECOMENDACIONES: Excelente, si continua asi usted es un genio.\n\n");   
        }   
        else
       {    
           if(nota>=8.5)
           {     
               printf("\nNOTA EQUIVALENTE EN STANDARD GRADING SYSTEM: B+\n");     
               printf("RECOMENDACIONES: Muy bien, su nivel es impresionante.\n\n");    
           }    
           else
           {     
               if(nota>=8)
               {      
                   printf("\nNOTA EQUIVALENTE EN STANDARD GRADING SYSTEM: B\n");      
                   printf("RECOMENDACIONES: Bien, su nivel es muy bueno.\n\n");     
               }     
               else
               {      
                   if(nota>=7.5)
                   {       
                       printf("\nNOTA EQUIVALENTE EN STANDARD GRADING SYSTEM: C+\n");       
                       printf("RECOMENDACIONES: Usted esta dentro del promedio, trate de no bajar.\n\n");      
                   }      
                   else
                   {       
                       if(nota>=7)
                       {        
                           printf("\nNOTA EQUIVALENTE EN STANDARD GRADING SYSTEM: C\n");        
                           printf("RECOMENDACIONES: Usted la va pasando, pero trate elevar su promedio.\n\n");       
                       }       
                       else
                       {        
                           if(nota>=6)
                           {         
                               printf("\nNOTA EQUIVALENTE EN STANDARD GRADING SYSTEM: D\n");         
                               printf("RECOMENDACIONES: Usted esta en la cuerda floja, un pequeno descuido \nlo pone en problemas.\n\n");        
                           }        
                           else
                           {/*nota mayor que cero pero menor que 6.*/         
                               printf("\nNOTA EQUIVALENTE EN STANDARD GRADING SYSTEM: F\n");         
                               printf("RECOMENDACIONES: Su nota sinceramente es mala, busque nuevas \ntecnicas de estudio.\n\n");        
                           }       
                       }      
                   }     
               }    
           }   
       }   
       printf("SI DESEA SALIR PRESIONE 1 O DE LO CONTRARIO PRESIONE OTRO NUMERO: ");   
       scanf("%d",&saliryesno);   
       if(saliryesno==1){    
           salir=1;   
       }  
   }
```

}

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Exacto. no podes. Salvo que.. multipliques por 10 lo que te pasaron y hagas el switch como si no hubiera decimales ;)

Comment: Puedes cambiar los ifs a algo sin 'else" como if (nota >=7 && nota <8) { } pero no creo que sea más claro. Tal vez pensaron en vb con "select/case"?

Answer (score 4):

> Comienzo a pensar que no sería posible porque debe evaluar una condición con decimales.

Y eso pasa porque te falta imaginación :)

---

Si el problema son los decimales, hagamos que los decimales no sean un problema. Hay que buscar la manera de transformar un valor con decimales en un índice que pueda ser usado en una instrucción `switch`; esto se puede hacer de manera natural usando una formación<sup>1</sup>:

```
float umbrales[] = { 6.f, 7.f, 7.5f, 8.f, 8.5f, 9.f, 10.f };
```

Un valor cualquiera estará entre uno u otro índice, esto lo podemos comprobar con un bucle:

```
int indice = 0;
float nota = .0f;
scanf("%f",&nota); 

for (; umbrales[indice] < nota; ++indice);
```

Una vez acabado el bucle anterior, `indice` contendrá la última posición en que la nota introducida es menor al umbral de nuestra colección de umbrales, por lo tanto:

```
switch (indice)
{
    case 0:
        printf("F");
        break;
    case 1:
        printf("D");
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("C");
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("C+");
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("B");
        break;
    case 5:
        printf("B+");
        break;
    default:
        printf("A");
        break;
}
```

Pero me parece una solución horrible, yo ni siquiera usaría una instrucción `switch`:

```
float umbrales[] = { 6.f, 7.f, 7.5f,  8.f, 8.5f,  9.f, 10.f };
char *grados[] =   { "F", "D",  "C", "C+",  "B", "B+", "A" };

int indice = 0;
float nota = .0f;
scanf("%f",&nota); 

for (; umbrales[indice] < nota; ++indice);

printf("Nota %s", grados[indice]);
```

---

1. También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Answer (score 2):

Efectivamente, en forma natural no se puede, ya que la sentencia `switch` en lenguaje c, según la literatura, es utilizando constantes. Ahora bien, se me ocurre un truco, usando sentencias de condición, y flujo orientado al resultado de dichas evaluaciones condicionales.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

        double nota;

        nota=(double)atof(argv[1]);

        printf("Nota Ingresada [%s] [%f]\n",argv[1],nota);

        switch(
                (nota>=6.0 && nota<7.0)?1:
                (nota>=7.0 && nota<7.5)?2:
                (nota>=7.5 && nota<8.0)?3:
                (nota>=8.0 && nota<8.5)?4:
                (nota>=8.5 && nota<9.0)?5:
                (nota>=9.0)            ?6:
                -1   /*para simular el default de switch*/
               ){
        case 1:
                printf("\nNOTA EQUIVALENTE EN STANDARD GRADING SYSTEM: D\n");
                printf("RECOMENDACIONES: Usted esta en la cuerda floja, un pequeno descuido \nlo pone en problemas.\n\n");
                break;

        case 2:
                printf("\nNOTA EQUIVALENTE EN STANDARD GRADING SYSTEM: C\n");
                printf("RECOMENDACIONES: Usted la va pasando, pero trate elevar su promedio.\n\n");
                break;

        case 3:
                printf("\nNOTA EQUIVALENTE EN STANDARD GRADING SYSTEM: C+\n");
                printf("RECOMENDACIONES: Usted esta dentro del promedio, trate de no bajar.\n\n");
                break;

        case 4:
                printf("\nNOTA EQUIVALENTE EN STANDARD GRADING SYSTEM: B\n");
                printf("RECOMENDACIONES: Bien, su nivel es muy bueno.\n\n");
                break;

        case 5:
                printf("\nNOTA EQUIVALENTE EN STANDARD GRADING SYSTEM: B+\n");
                printf("RECOMENDACIONES: Muy bien, su nivel es impresionante.\n\n");
                break;

        case 6:
                printf("\nNOTA EQUIVALENTE EN STANDARD GRADING SYSTEM: A\n");
                printf("RECOMENDACIONES: Excelente, si continua asi usted es un genio.\n\n");
                break;

        case -1: /*simula default*/
                printf("\nNOTA EQUIVALENTE EN STANDARD GRADING SYSTEM: F\n");
                printf("RECOMENDACIONES: Su nota sinceramente es mala, busque nuevas \ntecnicas de estudio.\n\n");
                break;
        }

        exit(0);
}
```

espero te sirva este ejemplo.

Comment: ¡Muy ingenioso!  +1

Comment: A mi más que ingenioso me parece impráctico, difícil de mantener, difícil de leer y propenso a errores. Además, ha cambiado la lógica original de pedir datos por consola a recibir datos por parámetros y ha pasado a usar `double` en lugar de los `float` del autor original sin explicar por qué.

Comment: veo que no has entendido que es un ejemplo, y presumo que tampoco leiste que la solicitud era no utilizar sentencias if

Comment: Tal vez no lo he entendido @RodrigoBurgosMella , pero eso no quita que tu ejemplo sea impráctico, difícil de mantener, difícil de leer y propenso a errores. Por otro lado, cambias la lógica de obtención de datos y te saltas la restricción de no usar sentencias `if` al usar el operador ternario (que es un azúcar sintáctico de un `if` con capacida de asignación).

Comment: creo que una condición no se puede evaluar si no es con eso, con una elemento condicional, incluso tu ejemplo con vectores (o arrays), tampoco es tan mantenible, y ojo, el ciclo for tiene una condición implícita, la idea es entregar una ayuda, no hacerles el código, celebro tu opinión, y celebro tu código (que tampoco se ve muy practico),  y soluciones como opiniones pueden haber muchas. Un abrazo

Comment: Es objetivamente más práctico, fácil de mantener y leer una formación de varemos que un encadenamiento de operadores ternarios anidados, puedes comprobarlo fácilmente añadiendo o quitando varemos: en una solución escribirás más y podrás cometer más errores que en la otra. El ciclo `for` tiene una condición implícita, mientras que tu encadenamiento de operadores ternarios anidados tiene seis condiciones explícitas. Soluciones, como opiniones, hay muchas; pero en determinados contextos, unas soluciones son más prácticas que otras.

Answer (score 1):

Para usar el *switch* otra opción (de filosofia similar a la respuesta de PaperBirdMaster, pero de ejecución diferente) se basaría en que los límites entre niveles están en los números enteros y en los números enteros + 0.5.

De esta forma si multiplicamos por dos las notas también multiplicamos también los límites entre niveles, que quedan todos como números enteros.

La conversion a *int* te elimina los decimales de la nota y te permite usar el switch directamente:

```
float nota = ... // Asignar valor
int notaDoble = (int) (nota * 2);
switch (notaDoble) {
   case 12: // Nota original era mayor o igual a 6 y menor de 6.5
   case 13: // Nota original era mayor o igual a 6.5 y menor de 7
        printf("\nNOTA EQUIVALENTE EN STANDARD GRADING SYSTEM: D\n");         
        printf("RECOMENDACIONES: Usted esta en la cuerda floja, un pequeno descuido \nlo pone en problemas.\n\n");        
        break;
   case 14: // Nota original era mayor o igual a 7 y menor de 7.5
        printf("\nNOTA EQUIVALENTE EN STANDARD GRADING SYSTEM: C\n");        
        printf("RECOMENDACIONES: Usted la va pasando, pero trate elevar su promedio.\n\n");       
        break;
   case 15: // Nota original era mayor o igual a 7.5 y menor de 8
        printf("\nNOTA EQUIVALENTE EN STANDARD GRADING SYSTEM: C+\n");       
        printf("RECOMENDACIONES: Usted esta dentro del promedio, trate de no bajar.\n\n");      
        break;
   case 16: // Nota original era mayor o igual a 8 y menor de 8.5
        printf("\nNOTA EQUIVALENTE EN STANDARD GRADING SYSTEM: B\n");      
        printf("RECOMENDACIONES: Bien, su nivel es muy bueno.\n\n");
        break;
   case 17: // Nota original era mayor o igual 8.5 y menor de 9
        printf("\nNOTA EQUIVALENTE EN STANDARD GRADING SYSTEM: B+\n");     
        printf("RECOMENDACIONES: Muy bien, su nivel es impresionante.\n\n");
        break;
   case 18: // Nota original era 9
   case 19: // Nota original era 9.5
   case 20: // Nota original era 10
        printf("\nNOTA EQUIVALENTE EN STANDARD GRADING SYSTEM: A\n");    
        printf("RECOMENDACIONES: Excelente, si continua asi usted es un genio.\n\n");
        break;
   default: // La nota original era 6 o menos
      printf("\nNOTA EQUIVALENTE EN STANDARD GRADING SYSTEM: F\n");         
      printf("RECOMENDACIONES: Su nota sinceramente es mala, busque nuevas \ntecnicas de estudio.\n\n");
}
```

Para las notas menores a 6 hay varias opciones:

- Puedes poner todos los *case* (del 0 al 11) que faltan.
- Como son las más numerosas, puedes ponerlas en una cláusula *default*.

Un punto importante es si has comprobado que la nota es válida (el valor original estaba entre 0 y 10). Si estás seguro antes del *switch* que la nota es válida, entonces

```
default:
    printf("\nNOTA EQUIVALENTE EN STANDARD GRADING SYSTEM: F\n");         
    printf("RECOMENDACIONES: Su nota sinceramente es mala, busque nuevas \ntecnicas de estudio.\n\n");
```

Si no has comprobado antes que el valor de la nota sea legal, si usas la cláusula *default* de esta forma antes tendrás que hacer la comprobación

```
default:
    if ((nota < 0) || (nota > 6)) {
         printf("\nEl valor %f es incorrecto, introduzca un valor correcto: F\n", nota);
    } else {
         printf("\nNOTA EQUIVALENTE EN STANDARD GRADING SYSTEM: F\n");         
         printf("RECOMENDACIONES: Su nota sinceramente es mala, busque nuevas \ntecnicas de estudio.\n\n");
    }
```

Si usas *case* del 0 al 11, entonces la cláusula *default* solo se ejecutará cuando cuando *nota x 2* no esté entre 0 y 20 (es decir, *nota* no está entre 0 y 10) así que en *default* solo pones el mensaje de error.